# what`s the best way to make babel6 support Array.from in webpack?

Tags: webpack, babeljs, ecmascript-6

I'm using a webpack config below:

```
    var path = require('path');
var webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
    plugins: [
        new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
            'fetch': 'imports?this=>global!exports?global.fetch!whatwg-fetch'
        })
    ],
    entry: {
        demo1 : ['babel-polyfill', './src/js/page/demo1.js']
    },

    output: {
        path: 'dist/js/page',
        filename: '[name].js'
    },
    devtool: 'eval-source-map',
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                include: [
                    path.resolve(__dirname, "src")
                ],
                exclude: path.resolve(__dirname, "node_modules"),
                loader: "babel-loader",
                query: {
                    plugins: ['transform-runtime'],
                    presets: ['es2015', 'react']
                }
            },
            { test: /\.scss$/, loader: 'style!css!sass?sourceMap'}
        ]
    },
    resolve: {
        root: path.resolve(__dirname, "src"),
        extensions: ['', '.js', '.json', '.scss']
    }
};
```

As it shows, I merge the whole `babel-polyfill` module to the entry file `demo1.js` to support `Array.from`. But I don`t think it`s a good idea to do this cuz it will heavier the entry file too much.

So is here any `loader`/`plugin`/`preset` that I could use to support `Array.from` in webpack as what `babel-polyfill` does?

Comment: AFAIK, babel-runtime loads the polyfill as well.

Comment: Chances are, you want the whole polyfill if you're working in the browser. Are you seeing any actual downsides to your approach? This is generally what I recommend. You would not generally use `'transform-runtime'` at the same time though.

Comment: @FelixKling you\`re right I should remove that plugin in that case, but the point is, I prefer to use plugin rather then merge whole polyfill module into files for reasons. I thought using plugin would finally get the output file smaller in size(maybe it\`s incorrect?).besides, I don\`t want to add `babel-polyfill` each time I add a new entry file within `webpack.config.js`(in the scenario of using plugin, I just need to add the entry file only) . So is here any plugin could be used to replace `transform-runtime` which support `Array.from` additionally?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will want to integrate with [`core-js`](https://github.com/zloirock/core-js#basic) directly then, which is what Babel uses under the hood. Then, you can cherry-pick features you want to provide compatibility for by explicitly requiring individual modules.

```
require('core-js/fn/array/from');

// Then, from within any module:
Array.from(new Set([1, 2, 3, 2, 1])); // => [1, 2, 3]
```

This is what Babel 6 will effectively set up for you through presets.

Comment: Do I need to `npm install core-js`?  ( You say, Babel uses it under the hood, but I had no luck with that. Map, Set, and loads of stuff, but Array functions, i.e. `Array.includes()`, nope...

Answer (score 0):

I know this thread is old but I stumbled across it while googling.

Another way would be to ditch `babel-polyfill` and use `dynamic-polyfill`.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/dynamic-polyfill

You could go with something like

```
import polyfill from 'dynamic-polyfill'

polyfill({
  fills: ['Array.from'],
  afterFill() {
    // your code
  }
})
```

Then the browser downloads the polyfill only if it needs it.